# How can I get Windows Active Directory functionalities in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, server, active-directory

I want to get the same functionalities of Windows Active Directory using Ubuntu Server 12.04. Is there any tools to do that? and how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what functionality you talk about.

Samba4 IS AD and it works with Windows nodes as well. You can manage everything using even the standard windows tools part of RSAT ;)

Likewise-open has a commercial version that supports some group policy options that apply to Linux. Kind of removes the 'open' part of the name though...

If you just want shared login or shared profiles you can accomplish this using Samba or even just LDAP + any network filesystem.

For configuration management you can use one of many tools, I personally like Salt (saltstack.org), but Chef/Puppet/Juju are nice too.

Comment: it seems Salt(saltstack) is a good one. Could you please give me a link of installation how to of Salt?

Comment: @tuxtu That's in the Salt docs, right on their site ;)